# YUP enable validation of a property based on another property value

Tags: javascript, typescript, yup

I have a rate to validate only if delete =false. If not the validation is not required at all. I was trying below code, but it did not work. When delete = true, rate is NAN

```
charges: array().nullable().of(
        object().shape({
            rate: number().required().typeError("Rate missing")
                .when("delete", {
                    is: true,
                    then: number().notRequired()
                }
                )
        })
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to move `'number().when("delete"`, to `rate:` :

```
charges: array().nullable().of(
        object().shape({
          rate: number().when("delete", {
            is: true,
            then: number().notRequired(),
            otherwise: number().required("Rate missing")
          })
        })
    ),
```